# Three.js How can I use zoom via function call?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using Trackball Controls in a scene and I want to implement a zoom button(which calls a javascript function that will do the zoom), besides the mouse zooming functionality. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I also need to implement panning buttons...maybe the process is similar?

Comment: You might should be a little more specific. TrackballControls are probably not going to be a good fit for what you are trying to do. Are you trying to zoom on a keyboard button press, or on an onscreen button? Keyboard buttons for pan? Or on-screen pan arrows?

Comment: Trackball Controls seems perfect for the app we are building, but we want to implement zoom via button, besides the Trackball zoom functionality. And panning via buttons, complementing, rather than replacing, the Trackball controls.

Answer (score 1):

I am using click left or right button and hold for logarithmic zoom in or out.

```
/// listeners
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){e.preventDefault();}, false);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', toggleOn, false)
document.addEventListener('mouseup', toggleOff, false)

/// controls
        function toggleOn(event){
            if(t==0){
                button = event.which
                t=setInterval('mouseDown()',speed);
            }
        }
        function toggleOff(){
            if(t!=0){
                clearInterval(t);
                t=0;
            }
        }

        function mouseDown (event){
                if (button == 1){
                    camera.fov += speed                 
            } else if (button == 3){        
                    camera.fov -= speed 
                    }

        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        render();
```